# Lost ability to read files Windows IOT

Tags: c#, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I've been developing an app on a Raspberry Pi running Windows IoT.  I have code that successfully could read and write files from the documents folder.  Lately, I've mostly been working on the app on my local machine, since the development cycle is faster.

When I went to try to run the code on the Pi again, my program could no longer see the files in the document folder.  Figuring I messed something up, I rolled back to an earlier version of the code that worked.  I got the same result.

For reference this is the code I'm using:

```
StorageFolder documentsLibrary = await KnownFolders.GetFolderForUserAsync(null /* current user */, KnownFolderId.DocumentsLibrary);
sampleFile = (StorageFile) await documentsLibrary.TryGetItemAsync(filename);
```

The StorageFolder variable seems valid, but I get null for samplefile.  If I run

```
IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> itemsInFolder =
                 await documentsLibrary.GetItemsAsync();
```

I see the files listed.  I'm at a loss on why earlier versions of the code don't work.  The only things I can think of are:

- I'm using a different Pi. (I don't have access to the last one that
  worked) I don't believe that there is any specific setup I need to
  apply to the Pi.
- There's some file outside the project directory that
  is corrupted or out of date.
- Some permission is wrong or has expired.

Has anyone come across a similar problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The files I was trying to read in were csv files.  After I brought each file into Excel and saved it and moved it back to the Pi, the app started working again.  I'm not sure why the contents of the file were prohibiting the file from being seen.  I'm going to look at the files with a hex editor to find any differences.